# Testing null hypothesis

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

For the simple regression model

$$Y_i=\beta\cdot X_i + \epsilon_i\quad\text{ with }\quad\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$$

How do I create a statistical test for $H_0$: $\beta =0$?

I've derived the CI $100(1-\alpha)$ for $\beta$ and expressions for every estimation parameter.

Comment: Is your Alternative Hypothesis B > 0, B < 0 or B not equal to 0..? To answer your question, you can perform a hypothesis on B = 0.